# Ruby: Is there any way to create a program that can be opened by double clicking and that doesn't close instantly?

Tags: ruby

If I create a program, for instance, that just says `puts "Hello world!"` it will open and close instantly or if I create a program that just says

```
puts "Enter some text!"

response = gets.chomp

puts "You said '#{response}'"
```

it will close right after entering input with enter.

So, is there anything I can put in the code that will keep the program open? I've heard of solutions like putting `gets` at the end of the program but that doesn't wok for me. I also don't want to open it with command prompt since double clicking it seems to work other than that the program closes abruptly.

Comment: what your program does? how do you want it to close?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by open? Files can be open, but not programs: Programs run. If you want to keep your program running, just use an endless loop before you reach the last statement.

That much being said, you might be concerned about interfaces. There are basically two kinds of interfaces: Textual or graphical. Both have advantages and disadvantages. If you are into graphical interfaces, you might be interested in GUI gems such as `gtk2` / `gtk3`. You can use them to pop up windows with input boxes, buttons etc. that keep running until the user takes an action that closes them.

But you seem to be interested in textual interfaces. In that case, let me announce it to you that there is an excellent textual interface platform in Ruby: `irb`.

Newbies frequently make a mistake of reinventing REPL interface, like having main loop that always ask via `gets` what the user wants to do and giving options A, B, C, ..., or allowing the user to type in a command etc.

Thanks to `irb`, your program often does not need the main loop. Instead of using `gets` with a set of commands, you can simply define methods and let the user interact with them inside `irb`. To provide a concrete example, a newbie programmer might decide to write the following program:

```
loop do
  puts "Enter some text!"
  response = gets.chomp
  puts "you said '#{response}'"
end
```

This program provides its own REPL loop that echoes back whatever you type in. A more experienced programmer would realize that this is reinventing the wheel and would simply define a method `#echo`:

```
def echo text
  puts "you said '#{text}'"
end

echo "hello"
#=> you said 'hello'
```

Your program "ends" but `irb` REPL keeps running, it's there for you to type `echo "something"` as many times as you wish. The morale of the story is, in Ruby, avoid reinventing REPL interfaces unles you know what you are doing. Other good textual interface with additional capabilities is `pry` (`gem install pry`).

Comment: @boris What is the good book to learn OOP design principals, patterns ?